# Overleaf source does not work on desktop; fatal pdftex error, font not found

Tags: fonts, errors, thesis

I have written a report on overleaf, but now I have to continue on desktop. In Overleaf the report works fine, but if I download the source, both texworks and texmaker will fail to produce a pdf file. I downloaded the software last week, and checked for updates, so it should be up to date. The report is a document with class \documentclass[whitelogo]{tudelft-report}, which I downloaded from the university website (https://www.tudelft.nl/en/tu-delft-corporate-design/downloads/). The only change I made in the class document is to have bibliographystyle IEEEtran instead of tudelft-report. The .tex file looks like this and in overleaf it works just fine, it produces a content page, an empty page and a page with the text of the test .tex file, but on the desktop it only gives the error below:

```
\documentclass[whitelogo]{tudelft-report}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{changes}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

%% Use Arabic numerals for the page numbers of the chapters.
\mainmatter
\input{19_test.tex}

\bibliography{report}

%% Use letters for the chapter numbers of the appendices.
%\appendix

\end{document}
```

The test chapter looks like this:

```
\chapter{Test}
In this chapter nothing will be explained. In fact this chapter is not even necessary to understand the matter. Please do not read it.

\section{Nothing to see here}
I went camping one day, the dog got hypothermia, but otherwise it was a splendid experience.
```

This is the last piece of the log in Texmaker:

```
   Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 58.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 58.
(Report.aux)
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 58.
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 58.
Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `Report.out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck) Checksum: E9B2F4E441D3B385811B1DC2D43062C2;104.
LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryVeryEnd' on input line 58.
)
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
23682 strings out of 480799
429101 string characters out of 2905519
694666 words of memory out of 3000000
39144 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
556407 words of font info for 38 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
68i,11n,87p,450b,432s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file futb8r): Font futb8r at 795 not found
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

When I try to run the file in texworks also the font futb8r is not found, but I checked and the font is in folder C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\tfm\public\fourier in the miktex installation. I have tried renaming the 'fourier' folder, so miktex would reinstall the font by itself, but that gave new, different, errors. I reinstalled miktex to be on the safe side, but now it cannot find font futb8r again. Unfortunately, I do not remember what problem miktex had when I renamed the fourier folder. Does anyone know how to fix or circumvent this issue? I am not a computer expert, so if it is a more complicated solution, please give me some details on how to get there.

Kind regards, Julia

Comment: Try installing fourier via the miktex colsole, this auto install feature does not always go as planned

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

The installation was on the local C drive, but the files were on a (protected?) network drive. I have moved them from the network drive to the C drive and it compiles fine now, also when I put the 'real' chapters as input. I saw some issue with access in the logs, so this seemed like a logical thing to try. Thank you for thinking along and maybe this will help someone else.